# How can I display an image when hovering over text on my wordpress web page

Tags: wordpress, hover, blogs

Ok geeks...

I've got a folder containing images of hundreds of players.

The images are named with the player name:

"John Doe"
"Jane Doe"

I would like to display the player image anytime you hover over the player name text.

Any ideas how I should go about this?

Answer (score 1):

look at tippy plugin

http://croberts.me/projects/wordpress-plugins/tippy-for-wordpress/

Its exactly what your looking for.

for an example see - http://scrobbn.com/cakedogg-and-presentcat/

I found that I had to turn off mobile browsing as the images didn't fit on iphone screen in portrait.

google "viewport wordpress" on how to comment out the code in header.php

I'm sure if you changed the options you could make it work for mobile, but I couldn't be bothered.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do google if you are starting from scratch. Check the following links, I hope this is what you need-

[LINK1](http://internetbrothers.com/dhtml_mouseover.htm)

[LINK2](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagetooltip.htm)

[LINK3](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnail2.htm)

In `Wordpress` check files that are responsible for those text display and then render those text according to your requirement as shown in above links.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some CSS skills to do so. Like using  tag to the text of the player name. Add a a.hover css to the same text with background image as the corresponding player.

Answer (score 0):

This short post explains how to create an image rollover animation for your Wordpress site in seconds using a plugin. No code necessary.

http://wpvisualslideboxbuilder.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-slide-box/